# Call Fortran dll with variable length array and array pointer from python

Tags: python, dll, fortran, ctypes

I have a fortran dll with the following subroutines.

```
subroutine test_doubles(d) bind(C,NAME='test_doubles')
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: test_doubles
    implicit none
    real(C_DOUBLE), dimension(:) :: d
    d(1)=d(1) + 1d0
end subroutine test_doubles


subroutine test_double_ptr(dptr) bind(C,NAME='test_double_ptr')
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: test_doubles
    implicit none
    real(C_DOUBLE), dimension(:),pointer :: dptr
    real*8, dimension(:),pointer :: data
    allocate(data(5))
    dptr=>data
end subroutine test_double_ptr
```

and want to call them from python. I have tried with this code:

```py
import ctypes
from _ctypes import POINTER
import numpy as np
c_double_p = POINTER(ctypes.c_double)
lib = ctypes.CDLL(filename)
arr = np.ones(5)
lib.test_doubles(arr.ctypes.data_as(c_double_p))
print(arr)
```

But it only works when `d` has a fixed dimension, and I do not know how to call `test_double_ptr`.

So is it possible to call these subroutines from python and how?

Comment: You want to pass around a simple address (scalar pointer, void pointer,...), working with array descriptors is very very tricky.

Comment: You're also going to need to pass the dimension(s) of the array in the call to make it work with non-hardcoded sizes.